# Why does React rerender my component and it doesn't use CSS animation?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-dom

This is live site: https://luxury-stroopwafel-b36b51.netlify.app/
Here is Github Repo:https://github.com/FullStackPete/CatMemoryGame

I have a problem with animations. When I click on the image of a cat - the array with cat data is being shuffled and then it is being rerendered. So it goes like this: You click on a cat -> the card flips -> allData array is getting shuffled -> the card (should) unflip with animation.
However you might notice, that ONLY the Cards which have the same ID after the flip are getting animated. All the cards that got shuffled are immediately 'rendered' as `cardIsActive(false)`- which is my state responsible for flipping the card. When I comment out the line `shuffleData(allData);` all the animations are being done properly, but the cards aren't getting shuffled so the game makes no sense. Please help me with this one.

Library responsible for flipping (although I don't think that it's causing problems): https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-card-flip

App.jsx

```
const shuffleData = (array) => {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
    return array;
  };
  const handleHowToPlayClick = () => {
    setShowInstructions(!showInstructions);
  };

  const handleCardClick = (data) => {
    setCardIsActive(false);
    setTimeout(()=>{
      setCardIsActive(true);
    },500);
    if (!pickedCards.includes(data.id)) {
      setPickedCards((prev) => [...prev, data.id]);
      setCardsLeft((prev) => prev.filter((item) => item !== data.id));   
      shuffleData(allData);
      
      if (pickedCards.length >= highestWin) {
        setHighestWin(pickedCards.length);        
      }
    } else {
      //Lose Logic
      setLose((prev) => prev + 1);
      setCurrentRound(3);
      setPickedCards([]);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    
    if (pickedCards.length > highestWin) {
      setHighestWin(pickedCards.length);
    }

    if (cardsLeft.length === 0) {
      setWin((prev) => prev + 1);
      setCurrentRound((prev) => prev + 2);
    }
  }, [cardsLeft]);
return (
//code responsible for rendering - not important
)
```

Cards.jsx

```
export function Cards({  handleCardClick,  setAllCards,  setCardsLeft,  lose,  allData,  setAllData,  cardIsActive,  win,  currentRound,
}) {
  const chunkSize = 3; 
  const CatApi = `https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?limit=${currentRound}&api_key=${
    import.meta.env.VITE_CatApiKey
  }`;
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(CatApi);
        setAllData(res.data);
        const cardIds = res.data.map((data) => data.id);
        setAllCards(cardIds);
        setCardsLeft(cardIds);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error fetching data: ", err);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [lose, win]);
  const chunkedData = Array.from(
    { length: Math.ceil(allData.length / chunkSize) },
    (_, index) => allData.slice(index * chunkSize, (index + 1) * chunkSize)
  );
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center mt-8">
      {chunkedData.map((chunk, index) => (
        <div className="flex flex-row" key={index}>
          {chunk.map((data) => (            
            <>
              <Tilt
                tiltMaxAngleX="15"
                tiltMaxAngleY="15"
                key={data.id}
                className="!p-0 m-4 background-color  !rounded-xl aspect-[3/4] max-h-60 min-h-60 lg:max-h-80 lg:min-h-80"
              >
                <ReactCardFlip
                  flipDirection="horizontal"
                  isFlipped={cardIsActive}
                >
                  <img
                    onClick={() => handleCardClick()}
                    className="aspect-[3/4] max-h-60 min-h-60 lg:max-h-80 lg:min-h-80 rounded-xl card-shadow hover:cursor-pointer"
                    src={CardBackground}
                  />
                  <img
                    onClick={() => handleCardClick(data)}
                    className="object-cover aspect-[3/4] max-h-60 min-h-60 lg:max-h-80 lg:min-h-80 rounded-md card-shadow hover:cursor-pointer"
                    key={data.id}
                    src={data.url}
                    //
                  />
                </ReactCardFlip>
              </Tilt>
            </>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a rendering problem. Turns out that after I shuffled the data there was no followup re-render. So I added a special state just for this  `const [render, setRender] = useState(-1);`
And after that added some timeouts in my handleCardClick:

```
    const handleCardClick = (data) => {
    setCardIsActive(false);
    if (!pickedCards.includes(data.id)) {
      setPickedCards((prev) => [...prev, data.id]);
      setCardsLeft((prev) => prev.filter((item) => item !== data.id));

        setTimeout(()=>{shuffleData(allData);},100)
      setTimeout(() => {
        setRender((prev) => prev + 1);
      }, 650);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setCardIsActive(true);
      }, 1000);
      if (pickedCards.length >= highestWin) {
        setHighestWin(pickedCards.length);
      }
    } else {
      //Lose Logic
      setCardIsActive(false);
      setLose((prev) => prev + 1);
      setCurrentRound(3);
      setPickedCards([]);
    }
  };
```